# prove $|A\times B|=|A|\times|B|$ using induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Prove that |A × B| = |A| × |B| for finite sets A, B.

What should be the base case for this?

ALso, for the inductive step, if I take |A|=m and |B|=n, then should I take |A|=m+1 and |B|=n+1 and prove it using induction?

Answer (score 1):

Prove this by induction on $n$:

> If $|A|=n$ then for all finite sets $B$, we have $|A\times B|=n\cdot |B|$.

And the base case is of course for $n=0$.

Comment: I got this. Base case proved. For inductive hypothesis, I assumed A=m and B=n. thus,  |A| × |B| =mn. Now, let a=m+1 and b=n+1 , this  |A| × |B| =(m+1)(n+1)=mn+m+n+1.     I dont know if I am doing it right because from this step I am stuck.

Comment: @JanviBalani Do not increment $m$. You're doing induction on $n$, not on $m$.

Comment: Then I am getting something like, |A| × |B|= A * (n+1). I dont know how to move further